# ListView Update Extremely Slow When Grouping Is Used

Tags: wpf

From my understanding, the default ItemsPanel for ListView is VirtualizingStackPanel.  When I create a GroupStyle for my list view, the refresh rate is terrible.  Based on comments in this post

[WPF ListView Very Slow Performance - Why? (ElementHost, or Other Reason?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296533/wpf-listview-very-slow-performance-why-elementhost-or-other-reason)

GroupStyle overrides the default VirtualStackPanel with StackPanel.  I have explicitly declared a VirutalzingStackPanel as my ListView's ItemsPanel, but performance is still bad.  Why is grouping so slow?  More than likely there is something going on with grouping I don't understand.

Comment: From your problem statement.  "GroupStyle overrides the default VirtualStackPanel with StackPanel."  Does not matter if you declared a VirtualStackPanel.

Comment: So no workaround using Grouping?  Seems like a useless feature if it's not going to perform at the rate of a ListView with no Grouping.

Comment: Complain to Microsoft not SO.

Comment: Was your comment addressing my question or my statement?  There is no workaround to allow grouping with a virtual container?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this my friend? Have the exact same problem here. I wish you included some code here then we could see what's your approach. Are you adding grouping from XAML or from the code?

Answer (score 4):

As the author of the post below mentions

> In a normal WPF ItemsControl that virtualizes, such as ListBox or ListView, virtualization turns off when you turn grouping on. This
>   sample shows how to achieve the same visual look of grouping and much
>   of the same API while still having virtualization.

Have a look at this solution developed in the sample project. However, not an easy or straight forward method at all.

[Grouping and Virtualization](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Grouping-and-Virtualization-56e7d3fe#content)

Remember that this method is suggested for .NET 4.0 and earlier. I believe there are new methods introduced in the .NET 4.5 which deal with this situation such as `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping` property. However I haven't tested this since I don't have an access to .NET 4.5 atm.

[VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel.isvirtualizingwhengrouping(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether this VirtualizingPanel
>   virtualizes the items in its collection when it displays groups.

Comment: Using `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping` makes a huge difference, thanks.

Comment: Saved my day. `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping` works very well